# What is the difference between Lucene query language and KQL

Tags: kibana

Kibana ver >= 7.0 offers KQL by default for the search dropdown but also supports what seems to be old Lucene syntax. 
Often it complains annoyingly that "You might be using Lucene but KQL is selected" when trying to search.
Going to the suggested links:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.7/lucene-query.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.7/kuery-query.html

I don't see any differences. What are the key differences between them? Can someone give query examples highlighting these differences?

Comment: I have the same question. A quick Google search seems to indicate that KQL is mostly based on Lucene except for a few minor differences, some of which is listed [here](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/elasticsearch-lucene-kibana-query-language/) under the section _Kibana Query Language (KBL) versus Lucene_

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The current documentation for [KQL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kuery-query.html) and [Lucene query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/lucene-query.html) shows the syntax of both for various types of queries. I will summarize the main differences:

#### 1. Dropdown Suggestions

It seems that KQL enables getting suggestions for fields, values and operators as you type your query, while this feature is not present when using Lucene. (This feature requires the “Basic Tier” or above.)

#### 2. Range Queries

To find content where `count` is greater than or equal to `5`: the KQL syntax is `count:>=5`, while the Lucene syntax is `count:[5 TO *]`.

To find content where `account_number` is greater than or equal to 100, but less than 200: the KQL syntax is `account_number:>=100 and account_number:<200`, while the Lucene syntax is `account_number:[100 TO 200}`.

#### 3. Operators

The KQL documentation outlines the Boolean operators `or`, `and` and `not`. The upper case versions (`OR`, `AND` and `NOT`) also work. The documentation specifies that `and` has a higher precedence over `or`, which is the usual operator precedence rule.

The Lucene documentation specifies the following:

> The preferred operators are `+` (this term must be present) and `-` (this term must not be present).

For example, `brown +fox -news` specifies that `brown` is optional, `fox` must be present, and `news` must not be present.

Lucene also supports `AND`, `OR` and `NOT`, but only in uppercase. So, if you try using `and`, it will be taken as the literal word. Also, Lucene supports `&&`, `||` and `!`. However, the documentation states that all of these operators do not honor the usual operator precedence rules, and advises the use of parentheses whenever multiple operators are used together.

#### 4. Exist queries

To find documents that contain the field `response`: the KQL syntax is `response:*`, and the Lucene syntax is `_exists_:response` (`response:*` also works in Lucene, but the behavior if the value of the field is an empty string might be different).

#### 5. Wildcards

For KQL, the documentation only mentions the `*` wildcard, which matches zero or more characters. There is no mention of `?`, so I assume it does not exist. In Lucene, `?` exists and matches a single character.

In KQL, escaping the wildcard character is never necessary when using it as a wildcard, so we can have something like `book.*:(quick or brown).` In Lucene, it seems that the wildcard needs to be escaped when used as part of the field name. The example given is `book.\*:(quick OR brown)`.

#### 6. Nested queries

The syntax for nested queries seems to be different as per the documentations.

#### 7. Extra Features in Lucene

The KQL documentation does not mention regular expressions, fuzzy search, nor boosting; so they are probably not supported. Lucene supports them.

Comment: according to latest [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/lucene-query.html): The main reason to use the Lucene query syntax in Kibana is for advanced Lucene features, such as regular expressions or fuzzy term matching. However, Lucene syntax is not able to search nested objects or scripted fields.